# cloudfront cache with CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer header

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I am new to Cloudfront and trying to maintain and access Cloudfront cache effectively.

If I whitelist CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer header, Will Cloudfront start maintaining the cache based on each user agent?

or it will just maintain whether the request is from mobile or not ?

Thanks,
Manish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudfront will not maintain the cache for each User-Agent.

In fact, Cloudfront discourages to whitelist headers which can have a lot of possible values as it will increase the number of cached copies on the CDN and also increase the number of requests which are sent to the origin.

It will cache the response sent from the origin server based on the `Cloudfront-Is-Mobile-Viewer` header only. So, for all mobile devices which are detected by `Cloudfront-Is-Mobile-Viewer` header the same cached content will be delivered to the end users.